# Is there a way to turn off autosave feature in Lion OS X?

Tags: macos, autosave

How can I turn off the [autosave](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4753) feature on all applications in lion?

Comment: If you're looking how to disable Versions (not Autosave), here's the procedure: [How to disable Versions in OS X Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37363/14994)

Comment: Since there is now a correct answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/disable-auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x-lion/, I flagged this as a duplicate, seeing as this question has an incorrect answer..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.pubarticles.com/article-2-ways-to-disable-autosave-and-versions-on-mac-os-x-lion-1311670708.html

: Disable Autosave and Versions on Lion - Setting

> 1. Go to System Preferences > General
> 2. Untick "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps".
> 3. Then reboot.

Comment: Odd. It probably is. I wonder what's the difference between time machine and a setting...

Comment: This answer is completely wrong; this only disables the automatic reopening of windows when you quit an app. It does NOT disable autosaving.