# Can revisions, auto save and versions be completely and permanently neutered from OS X?

Tags: macos, versions, autosave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to completely disable auto-save and versions in Mac OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/how-to-completely-disable-auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x-lion)

I have given these changes a good try and they irritate me more than they should. I want "auto-save", "revisions" and "restore-windows" and all of the rest of it to go away, to nerver come back, and hopefully to not cause instability when software updates arrive in the future. (I know this last one is impossible to guarantee so I'll have to have good backups and avoid updates in general)

On a technical level - can the **.DocumentRevisions-V100** storage directory be disabled and perhaps cleanly stop these functions? They go against the grain formed by long time Mac OS X user's expectations and interrupt my workflow at just the wrong times.

In short - can the simplicity of Snow Leopard be restored to Mountain Lion?