# Close a file TextEdit without saving

Tags: textedit

Every time I close (command-W) a file I'm editing in TextEdit, it will save any changes without even ask me (and several of those times, I didn't want the changes to be saved).

I couldn't find any option on the Preferences to disable this. Is there any hidden preference that can disable this behaviour as it's really annoying?

Comment: This is a special case of the general rule covered here:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/how-to-completely-disable-auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Let us know if you don't get how to implement this change, but it's basically change TextEdit for Preview in the example answer given. Your wording here will help others find the answer we have on the site. Thanks!