# How delete an application that is bundled with macOS?

Tags: terminal, textedit, macos

**Backstory:**

I am running macOS Sierra and use TextEdit a lot. The problem is that I hate the Versions save schema that causes the universal Save As shortcut of <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to instead create a copy of the document. I also hate how Auto-Save makes permanent changes to documents I don't want to modify when I'm tentatively modifying a work-in-progress. Since the introduction of these nuisance features in Lion I have always backed up and then replaced TextEdit.app with the legacy 1.6 version from Snow Leopard.

**The problem:**

Today when I tried to delete TextEdit.app from my Applications folder using this Terminal command

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

I got this error

```
rm: TextEdit.app: Operation not permitted
```

I was surprised to find that I can't kill it, even with sudo.

***How can I actually get rid of an application that is bundled with macOS?***

**What I've tried so far:**

I followed the instructions in [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/05/delete-safari-mail-facetime-other-default-mac-os-x-apps/), but it didn't work. I also read [this SE answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52390/123184), which *almost* accomplishes the same solution by means of disabling Versions and Auto-Save, but then I don't get the benefit of legacy TextEdit's temporary backup saving feature. See the part in the answer stating "This effectively disables the old-style, pre-Lion autosaving completely".

So I think deleting the newer TextEdit v1.12 and replacing it with the legacy v1.6 is still the best option, however I can't get my system to delete it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's apps in /Applications and /Applications/Utilities as well as some other usually invisible system files and folders are protected by [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) in El Capitan and later. You have to disable SIP temporarily to remove apps fallen into disgrace.

1. [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless” on OS X 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)
2. Reboot to your main system and remove the app with `sudo rm -rf /Applications/TextEdit.app`.
3. Enable SIP again by booting to Recovery Mode gain but entering `csrutil enable` in Terminal.app.

---

After a system update or upgrade TextEdit may reappear because it was updated.

Comment: Thanks! I won't get a chance to try this out until probably Monday, but it looks promising. Once I can confirm it worked I'll accept your answer. :-)