# Is there an easy way to remove some of the built-in apps on macOS Mojave?

Tags: mac, applications, mojave, mac-appstore

In the past I was able to do `sudo rm -rf /Applications/<app name>`. The following resources indicate that this will no longer work without dealing with System Integration Protection (SIP):

- [How delete an application that is bundled with macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299292/how-delete-an-application-that-is-bundled-with-macos)
- https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/976402-how-to-remove-defaultbundled-apps-in-macos-mojave/

The motivation is that I am not motivated to accept updates for apps that I do not expect to use within the foreseeable future.

Is there an **easy** way to remove some the built-in apps that I do not wish to update, such as GarageBand, Keynote, Pages, etc., without dealing with the SIP tool?

P.S. (edited): I completely understand that there may not be any *easy* or even *difficult* way to remove some built-in apps such as Safari, Siri, System Preferences, etc. This scope of this question is hereby limited to the some apps such as GarageBand, Keynote, Pages, etc.

Comment: Your first link *IS* how you remove the built-in apps. And that is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: The apps that cannot be removed are Apple-supplied apps that get updated as part of MacOS system updates. You can't chose "not to accept updates" for these apps without not accepting OS updates.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate as suggested in the comment above. This question has the word **easy** in both the title and body. I just updated the question to make this more clear and to qualify that I was really looking for an *easy* way to remove apps such as GarageBand, Keynote, etc.

Answer (score -2):

- Go to the `Applications` folder in the Finder tool;
- right-click on the unwanted application;
- click "Move to trash", and enter the password if requested by the system;
- then empty the trash.

Note the following exceptions:

- In case an unwanted application is in the `Utilities` subfolder, the first step should be to navigate into that subfolder.
- There are some applications such as Safari and Siri for which there is no "Move to trash" option.

Each of these steps should be well documented. I would be happy to add some more pointers upon request.

Comment: Not without turning offf SIP

Comment: The answer is already true as it stand for me on my macOS Mojave system, with the two exceptions that were already noted. I just updated the original question to clarify the original intent for an **easy** way, clarified that I did not want to deal with SIP, and explicitly limited the scope to exactly what kind of apps I wanted to remove.