# How to recover TextEdit files?

Tags: data-recovery, textedit

I just quit TextEdit and forgot to save my files that I have been working on for 2 weeks. I'm about to cry.

Please tell me how can I recover them?

Answer (score 4):

If you quit TextEdit, then reopening TextEdit will re-open all your documents. If it didn't give you an option to save, then they were stored by Restore in the Saved Application State. When you next open the app, they should have been there as the application state is restored. If this did not occur, then something else went wrong and the application state was either not saved or not restored correctly (e.g. force quit whilst opening will cancel restoration of application state).

If you closed TextEdit, then all the documents will be closed, and clicking Don't Save will delete them and you will not be able to recover them.

Comment: I clicked quit and it didn't even give me an option to save. It just closed and i reopened and they were gone.

Comment: @Tony If it didn't give you an option to save, then they were stored by Restore in the Saved Application State. When you next open the app, they should have been there as the application state is restored. If this did not occur, then something else went wrong and the application state was either not saved or not restored correctly (e.g. force quit whilst opening will cancel restoration of application state). I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Take a look at this set of responses http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/unsaved-files-in-os-x-lion   Im not very familiar with macs though and can't seem to get any of these things to work. That is also a very old conversation they were having and i think maybe the commands would be different now.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the name of your file(s), try using Spotlight (cmd + space) to search for them.